# Difference between Selenium WebDriver Implementations

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I recently developed a sample test in Selenium using IE WebDriver and it is  working fine on IE browser. I was wondering Why the same test would work on Chrome or Firefox just by changing the driver to Chrome or Firefox Driver without changing the test code. The test didn't work as it did on IE.

I was wondering if anyone knows or can point me to some link that shows the differences between web driver implementations?

I will explain my test in more detail.

I have a web site with one Dev Express AspxComboBox. This is a type ahead combo box which means  that it is initially empty and as the user enters input the combo box queries the database for data that contains the entered text. It displays 10 results at a time. If the user scrolls down more results are retrieved and added to the combo box.

My Test

> 1) Open up the browser with the given url
>
> 2) Type 'a' in the combo box
>
> 3) Check 10 records are populated.
>
> 4) Use the same query that the combo box uses and run it with the same
>   filtering.
>   Blockquote
>   5) Compare query results with the combo box  content.
>
> 6) Select the 10th element in the list to simulate scrolling and
>   getting more results.

The above test works fine with IE Web Driver.

When I changed it to Chrome Web Driver, I faced timing issues. Chrome Driver seems to be faster than IE Web Driver. I use the appropriate wait statements, but it doesn't work for me. For example, after the text, I put a wait to enter in the combo box, that is present until the combo box has 10 elements. Even though this wait succeeds, the Chrome Driver retrieves the first item in the combo box as empty. I passed this issue by putting a break point and make the test app wait long enough, then it worked, but then clicking the last item in the list became problematic. In IE I could just say click the 10th item, but the same code generated an exception in Chrome Web Driver. It was saying that the click won't be on the desired element.

The above challenges I faced made me think that there are differences between Web Driver implementations. Do people agree or not?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RoadMap ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: Also - didn't work is not very helpful.

Comment: _When I change it to Chrome Web Driver, I first had timing issues. Chrome Driver seems to be faster than IE Web Driver. I use the appropriate wait statements, but doesn't work._  Did you try increasing the number of seconds? `wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 40)
wait.until{driver.find_element(:name, 'your element')}`

Comment: wait statement succeeded, it didn't fail. Increasing the time is necessary if the condition is not met in the given time.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in ruby for Firefox originally, and the tested the same code in chrome with the same passing results.  I did get a few extra messages that I was able to turn off by removing extensions.

In order to test in chrome, you need the chromedriver which you can obtain here.

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

After getting that in your system path, it's just a matter of choosing your poison;

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

or

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

Happy coding!